# Asp.Net. Неверное отображение кириллицы при загрузке файлов на сервер

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip

При загрузке на сервер zip-архива с файлами и распаковки его получается что то вроде этого - "Ђ­ «ЁвЁзҐбЄЁҐ аҐиҐ­Ёп.DAT".
Чем это может быть вызвано и как это можно решить?

Comment: вызвано использованием не-латинских символов в именах файлов. ну и общей кривостью мега-комбайновой программы zip.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, она заключалась в кодировке стандартного архиватора.
Помогла кодировка `Encoding.GetEncoding(866)`